# breezejs : removing validators

Tags: breeze

According to the documentation, doing so should retrieve the validators of the given entity:

```
manager.fetchMetadata().then(function () {
    var creditorType = manager.metadataStore.getEntityType("Creditor");
    var creditorValidators = creditorType.validators;
});
```

creditorType.validators is an empty array. I don't understand why because when I inspect *dataProperties* on creditorType, the *validators* property is filled for each property.

Should the *validators* property on the *creditorType* object not be an aggregate of all the *validators* properties  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure where you read that in the documentation but...

Validators on the *entityType* are typically cross property validations, Validators on a *dataProperty* or *navigationProperty* of an entity are specific to a single property.  When you 'validate' an entire entity both the 'entityType' and all of the 'dataProperty' and 'navigationProperty' validators are executed. When you change a single property of an entity only the validators for that property are executed.

If you want all of the validators for an entity, this will be the entityType validators + all of the dataProperty validators + all of the navigationProperty validators.

Comment: ok, then I think my problem is that I don't understand what the entityType validators are. My understanding of validators is that they should validate an entity's properties. Why and when would I have validators at entity level ?

Comment: These will typically be cross-property validations, something like BeginDate < EndDate.  You really don't want this validation at a property level on both the BeginDate and the EndDate properties because then you will have trouble changing one without changing the other. For example, imagine trying to change the EndDate to before the BeginDate, with the plan of then changing the BeginDate.  As property validations this would not be possible because the validation fires as soon as the property is changed but as an entity level validation you can change both before validating.